# Where can I add new Admin in Sylius?

Tags: php, sylius

I just updated my sylius app. As per new commits, admin crud have been added. But I don't see it. Can someone share information about it?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue earlier today as well. I upgraded my sylius install it introduced sylius_admin_user table, but it was empty.

To get around it, i commented out the following lines on the file `/adsup/src/Sylius/Bundle/InstallerBundle/Command/SetupCommand.php`

```
//$this->setupCurrency($input, $output);
//$this->setupLocale($input, $output);
//$this->setupChannel();
$this->setupAdministratorUser($input, $output);
```

Leave the last one uncommented. 
Then run sylius:install:setup fill in the details and you will have a new admin user. It's a bit of a hack until someone adds an Add Admin User to go along with the Add Shop User

Actually i have just added a pull request for an admin-user:create command

Comment: I can't bellived there is no command to create a user/admin ... By the way this trick doesn't work for me as the code changed and the local is now a parameter of the setupAdministratorUser function. So I just ran the sylius:install:setup command

Comment: Yes code has changed significantly since my answer. https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/5941 - I have a Pull request on there but i think it's very out of date now

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

> If you want to try out new Sylius UI, please run the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ npm install
> $ npm run gulp
> ```

I missed this a couple of times too and also wondered how to get the new admin...

btw, the url has changed from /administration to /admin - be careful about that too :)

Comment: I know all that. But in Sylius Repository there was information that they have added an Admin CRUD. So I was looking for it. BTW Thanks for information :)

Comment: by Admin CRUD you probably mean Sylius Resource Bundle, right?